# iOS: UITextField not able to load

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a simple `ViewController` with a `UITextField`. I hooked it up with an `IBOutlet`. However, while loading, I keep getting the following error,

```
[UITextField isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9860ad0
```

I am not even using the variable in the source code at all. I am not sure whats going wrong.
 Can someone help me?

Comment: isEqualToString is NSString's method. Please check whether you have used the textfield property in place of NSString any where? Clean/Build your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the name of the UITextField does not coincide with any other ivar in your class. Also, if you are comparing the UITextField's text value to something, you might have missed to write UITextField.text

Comment: I am not using the name anywhere else... I verified it many times. Anyway, I changed the name to something unique. Then it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't call to `[UITextField isEqualToString:]` because
 1. It's not a static method.
 2. It's a method of NSString instance.

Instead do this:

```
[self.textLabel.text isEqualToString:YOUR_STRING];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your iVar for UITextField is coinciding with any of the NSString iVar. You can also check if the UITextField is correctly hooked up with the iVar.